# What does this Javascript statement (regular expression) mean?

Tags: javascript, regex

What does the RegEx test for here?

```
function chksql(){    
  if (/^\s*(?:delete|drop|truncate|alter)/.test(v)) return false;    
}
```

I just know it's mixed with regular expression, but can't figure out what it means.

Comment: More information on regular expressions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: please link the site that does this, because checking for this shit on the client side is a `drop table` waiting to happen

Comment: Ah well, at least this code would make it a little harder. You might have to say `DROP TABLE` instead! just_a_newbie, what I'm referring to here is the fact that this regular expression only matches the *lowercase* words, but SQL keywords are case independent and in fact are traditionally written in uppercase.

Answer (score 5):

it means its checking if `v` is a string that starts with zero or more white space charcters followed by **delete** or **drop** or **truncate** or **alter**

so if `v` were `"           alter"` this would return false.

see docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

I should add that checking against this happening on the client side is a really bad idea. It will be circumvented.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of good online tools for testing and exploring regular expressions these days.

One I like is [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/). Here's what it displays for your regular expression:

```
^\s*(?:delete|drop|truncate|alter)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PqGtfNDOAayuisgF)

To interpret that, you still need to do a bit of homework like finding out what `^` and `\s` mean, but the "railroad diagram" helps show what the regular expression is testing for. Just follow the lines to see what it will match. You can also try typing in test strings at the link above to see how it matches (or doesn't match) them.

Another good site is [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/). Here's [your regular expression there](http://regex101.com/r/yJ6mM9). They give you an English description of what the regular expression is looking for.

Also, heed mkoryak's advice about trying to sanitize SQL on the client!

[image]